# c# recursive search operation with List

Tags: c#, recursion

I have 2 lists of items with fileName and createdByDate. Here the filenames can repeat but the date may be different. How do i search and find out all the files with latest CreatedByDate. I want all unique records.

```
   Example 
   FileName: DBTestScripts/SQLParallel/Insert_50000_Sales
   CreatedByDate : '2018-08-07 12:12:12'

   FileName: DBTestScripts/SQLParallel/Insert_50000_Sales
   CreatedByDate : '2018-08-09 12:12:12'
```

Comment: I'm afraid this problem is not about recursion, but general question about searching in c#, try edit your question to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<File> files = new List<File>() {
                new File() { FileName = "DBTestScripts/SQLParallel/Insert_50000_Sales", CreatedByDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-07 12:12:12")},
                new File() { FileName = "DBTestScripts/SQLParallel/Insert_50000_Sales", CreatedByDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-09 12:12:12")}
            };

            var results = files.GroupBy(x => x.FileName).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedByDate).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class File
    {
        public string FileName { get;set;}
        public DateTime CreatedByDate { get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "jdweng". It helped a lot. :)

Comment: A GroupBy() create a two dimensional object : List<key,List<object>>.  So the select in my solution is enumerating through the keys and get the List<object> with the latest date.